# How to tell angular form custom directive is invalid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have custom angular directive:

```
<div class="input-group" name="name" ng-class="{ 'has-error has-feedback' : invalid }">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-paw"></i>&nbsp;{{label}}</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="ngModel" ui-mask="99.99.9999" ui-mask-placeholder ui-mask-placeholder-char="-" model-view-value="true" placeholder="mm.dd.yyyy" ng-required="required" />
    <span ng-show="invalid" class="form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-paw"></i></span>
</div>
```

Directive initialization code:

```
.directive("smth", function($rootScope) {
    var link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.invalid = false;
        scope.$watch("ngModel", function(value) {
            if(scope.ngModel) {
                scope.invalid = !$rootScope.timeStringValid(scope.ngModel);                }
            else {
                scope.invalid = false;
            }
        });
    };
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            name: "=name",
            label: "=label",
            ngModel: "=",
            required: "=required"
        },
        link: link,
        templateUrl: "smth.html"
    };
})
```

Usage of directive inside the form:

```
                <form class="form-horizontal" name="smthForm">
                    <div class="row">...</div>
                    <smth label="'Birth date'" ng-model="data.birthdate" type="birthdate" required="true"></smth>
                </form>
```

When directive input is invalid, appearance of it changes as expected. However, the form that holds directive doesn't know anything about its validity state and I can't figure out how to make it work manually. On the other hand, form somehow knows when the input is empty and becames invalid ("required" param works).
I tried several approaches based on $setValidity("smth", !scope.invalid), but failed, basically I can't understand what exact entity must have $invalid field in my custom directive to change it.
What should I add for the form to become invalid when internal directive invalid field is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ngModel` validators:

```
.directive("smth", function($rootScope) {
    var link = function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

        // Add custom validator
        ngModelCtrl.$validators["timeString"] = function(modelValue) {
            return !$rootScope.timeStringValid(modelValue);
        }
    };
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            name: "=name",
            label: "=label",
            ngModel: "=",
            required: "=required"
        },
        // require ngModel controller
        require: "ngModel",
        link: link,
        templateUrl: "smth.html"
    };
});
```

This way angular will include the validation errors to its `$invalid` property and the `$errors` (`myForm.myFieldName.$errors.timeString`)

Comment: Thank you! My main problem was in absense of "require: "ngModel"," in return object that lead to my ngModelCtrl undefined. It is really difficult to understand this addition, you saved a lot of my time.