# Plug a user directive to form.$valid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple directive:

myDirective.html:

```
<div class="my-directive" ng-class="{'on':status,'off':!status}" ng-click="onClick()">
    click me
</div>
```

myDirective.js:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'myDirective.html',
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.onClick = function () {
                $scope.status = !$scope.status;
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

I have a ng-form and I'm using this directive as a field of the form:

```
<ng-form name="frm">
    <div class="form-field">
        <input type="text" required ng-model="v1" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
        <my-directive status="v2" />
    </div>
    <input type="button" ng-disabled="!frm.$valid" value="save" />
</ng-form>
```

Live example in: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jonataspiazzi/4u767xs4/).

When I set some text in the input `frm.$valid` turn to `true` automatically. 
I want to apply to `my-directive` the same effect. Lets say...

> Consider `my-directive` as valid only when `status` is true.

And if `my-directive` is invalid the form should be invalid too.

Can I set this effect in `my-directive`? And how can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell angular form custom directive is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40992312/how-to-tell-angular-form-custom-directive-is-invalid)

Comment: Voted to close as a duplicate, basically you just need ngModel (and the ngModelController that comes with it) to mark flags for the element.